# MAUI iOS - App should not enabled when selecting multiple files for sharing

Tags: maui, maui-ios

In iOS device, open Files -> select more than one files from the files section -> click on share icon -> MAUI app displayed for sharing.

When i select more than one files, My MAUI ios app should not display the app from sharing.

I have added CFBundleDocumentTypes in the maui app to allow only specific document types can be shared with the mobile app. I haven't done any specific coding for this.

[image]

Any inputs for resolving this issue would be helpful.

Comment: Set ```LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace``` to false means not allowing the user to directly access files in your app. You may refer to [Sharing with the Files app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system#sharing-with-the-files-app).

Comment: Thanks, to make app to be not enabled for sharing when multiple files are selected, what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use share extension in MAUI. You could refer to [NSExtensionActivationRule](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsextension/nsextensionattributes/nsextensionactivationrule?language=objc)
. That means what you need to do is to define your own **NSExtensionActivationRule** in the info.plist for your Share Extension project.

A small example, if you want to  limit the max supprt number to 1 file, just set **NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount** to **1** (in the share extension's info,plist),

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
                    <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainInterface</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
</dict>
```

For more info, you may also refer to Apple docs at [App Extension Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html) about `NSExtensionActivationRule`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Liqun Shen-MSFT. But i am not using iOS extension. I have added an image on my question on top, please take a look. I am just trying to do a share from my iphone Files and my expectation is the app should not be displayed if multiple files are selected. I tried adding the extension key but that not helped.

Comment: What did you use for sharing?  Could you please share some relevant code?

Comment: I haven't done any specific coding, in Info.Plist I have added CFBundleDocumentTypes to allow only specific document types can be shared from ios device to the mobile app.

Comment: But I don't think using file association can achieve what you want. While share extension can set the rule for sharing.